# How to get URL parameters with Dojo toolkit

Tags: url, dojo, dojox.grid

I need know how can get a parameter from the URL. I mean if have

```
   page1.html?id=12345
```

I need to get the id from the URL, I know that in jQuery is 
        `$.url.param("id")`;

But in Dojo how it is done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The relevant function is [`dojo.queryToObject(string)`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/queryToObject) it returns an object containing the key-value pairs from the query string. This way, you can use either

```
dojo.queryToObject("id=12345").id
```

or

```
dojo.queryToObject("id=12345")['id']
```

Do note that this function receives only the query part of the url. You can get this information via `document.location.search`, as mentioned by Ghislain in the comments.

Comment: I suggest using `dojo.doc.location.search` to get the query part of the URL. You just have to remove the leading '?' before passing it to `queryToObject` : `dojo.queryToObject(dojo.doc.location.search.substr((dojo.doc.location.search[0] === "?" ? 1 : 0)))`

Answer (score 7):

In new dojo it's accessed with io-query:

```
require([
    "dojo/io-query",
 ], function (ioQuery) {
    GET = ioQuery.queryToObject(decodeURIComponent(dojo.doc.location.search.slice(1)));
    console.log(GET.id);            
});
```

Comment: +1. Note that `dojo.doc` became deprecated in Dojo 1.8.  Use `document` instead if using Dojo 1.9+.